# Cant Submit Form In Robot Framework Testing

Tags: php, html, testing, robotframework

I'm basically trying to test this submit form in my website using Robot Framework.

I firstly tried the "Submit Form" Keyword and that didn't work. So I decided to try the "Press Key" Keyword for enter (Being \13 for ASCII) Everything passes. It does in fact input the password and it does in fact press the enter key, but the form doesn't get submitted.

Robot Frame Work Code - Checking Login Form

```
| Open Admin Login And Check Field And Login
| | Click Element | ${Admin Link}
| | input password | admin-pw | ******
| | Press Key | admin-pw | \13
```

As I said, It technically Passes the test. But It doesn't send off the form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's not enough information. If you could add the HTML that you're submitting against, that would be good.

Now - there are two options. Either, your form identifier is wrong, or your page has a lot of JavaScript in it (based on AngularJS for example) and submitting forms has no meaning in that context.

Pressing a key, is not the right way to go in either case. You need to use click element instead (and click the "submit" button or it's equivalent).

To summarize:

1. You either have the wrong form identifier
2. Or you have a javaScript based page, and you should use "click element" instead.